# How to set a message on parent page using ui-bootstrap modal (scope issue)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have the following modal code:

```
var somemessage = null;
$scope.open = function() {
    var modal = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: '/App/Views/test.html',
        animation: true,
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false,
        ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
        ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
        controller: 'TestCtrl'
    });

    modal.result.then(function (message) {
            alert(message);
            $scope.succcess = message;
        },
        function(error) {
            $scope.error = error.data.error_description;
        });
}
```

I close it using:

```
$uibModalInstance.close('Success!');
```

However, I can see "Success" in the alert, but my page doesn't update, in fact it doesn't look like $scope.success is defined anymore.

```
<div class="help-block alert-success">
     {{success}}
</div>
```

I've tried instantiating $scope.success with no luck:

```
$scope.success = 'test';
```

How can I return a simple success message back to my parent page?

Comment: It should work. Is it because of the typo in `$scope.succcess`?

Comment: Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CFo60g8VsmWBfJQ2P52r?p=preview) demonstrating the functionality. @AnthonyC is most likely correct, this could simply be a typo.

Comment: Yep, it was the typo :) Thnx!